# How can I list out all current clusters when using a single linkage algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, hierarchical-clustering, linkage

I'm now doing clustering on python using `from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage`
From the manual I know that it gives result in this form --> `[A, B, length, #]`
which A and B is the indices of elements that are going to merge in this...stage(?), but can I get any information about clusters which is already merged but not going to participate in this stage?

For example, my dataset is:

```
A=[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],
   [10,1],[10,2],[10,3],[10,4],[10,5],
   [15,1],[15,2],[15,3],[15,4],[15,5],
   [30,1],[30,2],[30,3],[30,4],[30,5]]
```

and apply single linkage algorithm on it

```
Z = linkage(A, 'single')

Z=[[  0.   4.   1.   2.]
   [  1.  20.   1.   3.]
   [  2.  21.   1.   4.]
   [  3.  22.   1.   5.]
   [ 17.  19.   1.   2.]
   [  5.   9.   1.   2.]
   [  6.  25.   1.   3.]
   [  7.  26.   1.   4.]
   [  8.  27.   1.   5.]
   [ 18.  24.   1.   3.]
   [ 10.  14.   1.   2.]
   [ 11.  30.   1.   3.]
   [ 12.  31.   1.   4.]
   [ 13.  32.   1.   5.]
   [ 16.  29.   1.   4.]
   [ 15.  34.   1.   5.]
   [ 28.  33.   5.  10.]
   [ 23.  36.   9.  15.]
   [ 35.  37.  15.  20.]]
```

here I choose 5 to be the distance limitation in clustering, so I get

`[ 28.  33.   5.  10.]`

then I traced 28 and 33 back to the original indices

```
cut = 5
temp1 = []
temp2 = []
for i in range(len(Z)):
if Z[i][2] >= cut:
    temp1.append(Z[i])
for i in range(2):
    temp2[i].append(int(temp1[0][i]))
for j in range(0, len(temp2)):
try:
    g = max(temp2[j])
except:
    continue
G = int(g - len(A))
while g >= len(A):
    ind = temp2[j].index(g)
    temp2[j].append(int(Z[G][0]))
    temp2[j].append(int(Z[G][1]))
    del temp2[j][ind]
    g = max(temp2[j])
    G = int(g - len(A))
```

and found that

```
temp2 = [[8, 7, 6, 5, 9], [13, 12, 11, 10, 14]]
```

which means '28' stands for points `[10,1],[10,2],[10,3],[10,4],[10,5]` and '33' stands for points `[15,1],[15,2],[15,3],[15,4],[15,5]`, which clearly means that the cluster consist of [10,x] and the cluster consist of [15,x] are going to merge in this stage.

But obviously `[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5]` and `[30,1],[30,2],[30,3],[30,4],[30,5]` must have formed another two clusters in earlier stage, so at the moment before [10,x] and [15,x] merge , currently there are 4 clusters

So the result I want is like:

```
temp2 = [[8, 7, 6, 5, 9], [13, 12, 11, 10, 14], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

What should I do to get the later two clusters T^T??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage), `linkage` gives you the distance between clusters, which is the same as the cophenetic distance between elements in those clusters.  As described in [other documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster), `fcluster` will give you flat clusters, and if you specify `'distance'` as the criterion, will cut the dendrogram according to the cophenetic distance.

So you can get what you want by using `fcluster` to threshold the clusters at your chosen distance.  However, a slight wrinkle is that `fcluster` treats the threshold as the highest distance to lump, not the lowest distance to split, so if you use 5 as the threshold it will join the two clusters you're referring to and give you only three clusters.  You'll have to choose a threshold slightly less than 5 to get what you want.  For instance:

```
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy as clust
>>> clust.fcluster(Z, 4.99999, criterion='distance')
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

This is telling you which cluster each item is in.  To translate that back into lists of the indices in each cluster, you could use `np.where`:

```
>>> clusters = clust.fcluster(Z, 4.99999, criterion='distance')
>>> [np.where(clusters==k)[0].tolist() for k in np.unique(clusters)]
[[15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L],
 [0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L],
 [5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L],
 [10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L]]
```

In sum, the idea is to look at what you call the "distance limitation" and use `fclust` to get flat clusters with that distance (or rather, a slightly smaller distance) as the threshold.  This will give you the cluster number of each index, and then you can use `np.where` to get a list for each cluster.